# How to Localized WeekDay enums in select option list in Angular 8

Tags: angular, localization, html-select, angular8

I wanna create a simple drop down list in Angular containing weekdays and make them localized.

I found the WeekDay enum, which seems to be perfect for the job.

```
 public weekDays: WeekDay[] = [WeekDay.Monday, WeekDay.Tuesday, WeekDay.Wednesday, WeekDay.Thursday, WeekDay.Friday, WeekDay.Saturday, WeekDay.Sunday];
```

**App.Component.Ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeekDay } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public weekDays: WeekDay[] = [WeekDay.Monday, WeekDay.Tuesday, WeekDay.Wednesday, WeekDay.Thursday, WeekDay.Friday, WeekDay.Saturday, WeekDay.Sunday];

  public selectedWeekDay: WeekDay;

   constructor(        
        public translateService: TranslateService) { }
}
```

And then I create a Select Option in my html file

**App.Component.Html**

```
 <select>
     <option *ngFor="let day of weekDays" value="day">{{day}} {{day | date: 'EEEE' : '' : translateService.currentLang}}</option>                           
 </select>
```

Since I'm from Denmark, I would like to display the days in Danish, So I added the Translate service. This gives me a list of Thursday's and I know that this must be because, *{{day}}* is not of type *date*, but I can't seem to find any pipe for *WeekDays*. But I can't imagine that there shouldn't already be something built into Angular?

[image]

And last I would like to bind the selected WeekDay to a property

```
  public selectedWeekDay: WeekDay;
```

I have created a complete sample found here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slpqpy

Comment: *But I can't imagine that there shouldn't already be something built into Angular?*: try harder: there isn't any pipe translating WeekDays into Danish. There is this, though: https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleDayNames

Comment: @JBNizet It just seem strange to me that there is a DatePipe that can translate to a Week Day, but no way of using a WeekDay Enum together with a Date object or any custom way to get the translation that already exists.

But maybe I don't see what the real purpose of the WeekDay Enum is.

Comment: There is: https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleDayNames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended creating.

**app.component.html**

```
 <select>
 <option *ngFor="let day of weekDays" value="day">{{ 'weekday.' + day | translate}}</option>
 </select>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// ngx-translate
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

//Add Danish language
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDanish from '@angular/common/locales/da';

registerLocaleData(localeDanish, 'dk');

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }

// The HttpLoaderFactory is required for AOT (ahead of time) compilation.
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeekDay } from '@angular/common';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public weekDays: WeekDay[] = [WeekDay.Monday, WeekDay.Tuesday, WeekDay.Wednesday, WeekDay.Thursday, WeekDay.Friday, WeekDay.Saturday, WeekDay.Sunday];

  public selectedWeekDay: WeekDay;

   constructor(        
        public translateService: TranslateService) {
          translateService.addLangs(['dk', 'se']);
        translateService.setDefaultLang('dk');
        translateService.use('dk');
        }
}
```

**assets/i18n/dk.json**

```
{
  "weekday": {
            "1": "Mandag",
            "2": "Tirsdag",
            "3": "Onsdag",
            "4": "Torsdag",
            "5": "Fredag",
            "6": "Lørdag",
            "0": "Søndag"
        }
}
```

A running example can be found here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slpqpy

Comment: angular common do the job, see no reason to move such things into json. i mean getLocaleDayNames function